# Java Runtime not capturing STDOUT on Mac

Tags: java, macos, shell, stdout

Mac OS here, but **looking for a solution that is platform agnostic.** Also please note, even though Consul is mentioned here, it is just arbitrary and the solution should have nothing to do with, nor require knowledge of, Consul.

---

When I open a shell and run `consul -v` (to determine if [Consul](https://www.consul.io) is installed locally), I get the following STDOUT:

```
Consul v0.5.2
Consul Protocol: 2 (Understands back to: 1)
```

When I run the following code:

```
public class VerifyConsul {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream oldPS = System.out;
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc;

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream newPS = new PrintStream(baos);

            System.setOut(newPS);
            proc = runtime.exec(“consul -v”);
            proc.waitFor();

            String capturedOut = baos.toString();

            if(capturedOut.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(“Consul not found.”);
            }
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            System.setOut(oldPS);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the `IllegalArgumentException` stating that *Consul [is] not found*.

What is wrong with my code? Why isn’t it “hooking”/capturing STDOUT?

Comment: use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--

Comment: Thanks @RC (+1), is that cross-platform (will it work anywhere)?

Comment: java api is "platform insensitive" yes.

Comment: Thanks @RC (+1 again) - also just to clarify for future onlookers, you actually want `getInputStream()` since `Process#getInputStream()` is how you get the STDOUT from the underlying/external app **into** your Java app (it's a bit convoluted and backwards IMHO).

Comment: yes there's a catch with output/outputstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process#getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) to read STDOUT or [Process#getErrorStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--) to read STDERR

Here's an example (using `java` process and reading STDERR):

```java
package so32589604;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process proc = runtime.exec("java -version");
        proc.waitFor();
        // IOUtils from apache commons-io
        final String capturedOut = IOUtils.toString(proc.getErrorStream());

        System.out.println("output = " + capturedOut);
        if(capturedOut.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Java not found.");
        }
    }
}
```